# R / matlab: restricting which libraries can be loaded

Tags: r, matlab, testing, automation

For an ML course I'm TAing next semester, we're using an autograding system. We're asking students to do their own implementations of some standard algorithms, so we'd like to restrict students from loading certain libraries (with either a blacklist or a whitelist, not sure.)

Are there any reasonable ways to do this with R or matlab? Or is inspecting the source code (i.e. regex/grep) the best way to go?

Comment: Can you not just run on an installation without the packages installed, and without an internet connection to install new ones?

Comment: What's the point?  They can copy the source easily enough.  There are only so many ways to implement a trapezoidal rule integral.  The real WTF here is autograding.

Comment: You could try using Live-R (R in a browser, specially targetted at running courses in R, http://live-analytics.com/).  Not sure whether their admin tools currently let you restrict packages but they're very keen to add features if you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `trace` function to change the behaviour of `library`.  When the `library` function is called, the following code retrieves the name of the package that is passed to `library`, and then throws an error if it on the banned list.

```
 trace(
   base::library, 
   function() 
   {
     package_name <- if(parent.frame()$character.only)
     {
       parent.frame()$package
     } else
     {
       deparse(substitute(package, parent.frame()))
     }
     if(package_name %in% c("ggplot2", "lattice")) #or whichever packages are banned 
     {
       stop("The ", sQuote(package_name), " package is not allowed")
     }
   }
 )

 library(ggplot2)
 library("ggplot2", character.only = TRUE)
 library(plyr)
```

You'll also need to `trace` the `require` function.

---

Beware sneaky students: if they know that this is how you are preventing package loading, then they can turn tracing off in their script (and maybe reenable it afterwards).  You should perhaps check for calls to `trace`/`untrace`/`traceOn`/`traceOff` in their scripts too.  How much effort you put into this depends on how much manual looking at their code you are going to do and how honest your students are.  Weird evasive code like that should stand out if you read it.

Comment: At some point you should accept that if they are smart enough to get around methods like these that they should be considered as having "passed the test".